# Xcode how to fix problem "Unable to launch" in running on device?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been using lots of Xcode versions, but this problem "Unable to launch"

> Request to launch xcodetest.1 failed.
>   Domain: com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice
>   Code: 2
>   Failure Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. (null) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'my bundle identifier here'.  [full xcode error output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqe2R.png)

does not leave me.
 All I try is to run any application (empty too) from xcode on my device, but it always crashes. This crashes happen only on my device (iphone X), but when i change phone (iphone 7), everything works ok. There is something in code signing, but nothing from the web helps me. I tried cleaning certificates, using new apple account, even 100$ one (now i am using free acc), tried reinstalling xcode, reinstalling ios on iphone, switching developer profile to trusted in settings, editing schemes etc. 
[Xcode code signing settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maArq.png)

I have no idea what to do. the only way i can run apps is to apply them to testflight...

[iphone profile trusted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF0iR.jpg)

Comment: To run your app locally on a device you need a Development Certificate on your machine created through the Apple Developer Portal and synced to your machine, then selected in Xcode. I can highly recommend the Fastlane Tool named `match` to help create new Certificates and Provisioning profiles and then sync them between your various machines.

Comment: Apple has great docs (https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing/) around codesigning and Fastlane Match can be found here: https://codesigning.guide/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run using Xcode if you are using a `Distribution` Certificate.

Comment: so how can i fix it? i didn't set up certificates on signing this time. Xcode did it for me automatically.

Comment: You have to create a `Development` Certificate in the Apple Developper Console

Comment: when i go to https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/ to create it, it says "The selected team does not have a program membership that is eligible for this feature. If you need assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support. https://developer.apple.com/support"